# How can I fix my program so that it can work with any number of rows and column user asks?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // For you to test
        //int[][] testArray = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

        int[][] testArray = {
        { randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber() },
        { randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber() },
        { randomNumber(), randomNumber(), randomNumber() } };
        //
        // TO DISPLAY ARRAY
        printArray(testArray);


    } // end main

    // TO DISPLAY TABLES
    private static void printArray(int[][] array) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Ask the user
        System.out.println("How many rows: ");
        int rows= sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many columns: ");
        int columns= sc.nextInt();

        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; rows++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < array[rows].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(array[rows][columns] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }



    private static int randomNumber() {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 9);
        return random;
    }

}
```

Currently my program is working only with three rows and three columns. How can I make work so that it works with any rows and columns the user inserts?. And then my methods work with whatever the user insert?

Comment: Ask the number of rows and columns and the use a for loop to iterate over the values as needed

Comment: I don't think it's very clear what you're trying to achieve; that's a lot of code we must read to get an idea of what you're doing. Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok I left the part that I need help. If the user puts 5 rows and 5 columns that program shoudl diplay a array with 5 columns and 5 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a user inputted size, you can do the same thing you're doing in `printArray()` and then use those sizes to create the array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Ask array size to the user
    System.out.println("How many rows: ");
    int rows= sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many columns: ");
    int columns= sc.nextInt();

    // Fill array with random numbers
    int[][] testArray = new int[rows][columns];
    for (int i=0; i<testArray.length; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j<testArray[i].length; ++j) {
            testArray[i][j] = randomNumber();
        }
    }

    // TO DISPLAY ARRAY
    printArray(testArray);
} // end main
```

Also, you're using the array length instead of the current element when walking it:

This looks incorrect

```
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; rows++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array[rows].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(array[rows][columns] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Fix (note how `rows` and `columns` were replaced in the outer `for` and in the `print()`):

```
    for (int row = 0; row < columns; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < rows; col++) {
            System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: How can I put random numbers instead of it showing at zeros?

Comment: @ outlyer How can I return this to the main method?

Comment: private static int average(int[][] array){ 
  for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
    int rowPcol= row*col;
    int average= sum(array) / (rowPcol);
   
   }
   
  }
  return average(array);
   
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ClassName {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        //testArray will be axb dimensions.. depending on what user inputed
        int[][] testArray = new int[a][b];
    }
}
```

You can use scanner for user input as well. If you're learning java perhaps it's even easier to use Scanner. If you want or need to use BufferedReader and don't understand what "throws IOException" does, refer to this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

If you're in a hurry to implement this code just keep putting "throws IOException" on every method that uses .readLine() and read upon exceptions later.

I prefer to use BufferedReader because Scanner, in my experience, has been known to go crazy if you use it in a loop.

Comment: I need to use scanner

Comment: kk replace buffer with scanner